# Is it possible to do a masters in CS and a PhD in physics at the same time?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, masters, computer-science, physics

I’m a freshman in college and I’m a non-traditional student. I’m 45 years old with no previous degree other than high school here in the US.

After college, I want to pursue a Ph.D. in physics, however, I want to get a master's in computer science as well. I’m double majoring in both as an undergrad.

Comment: why? are money a concern for you or not?

Comment: The fact that you are capable of pursuing both at the undergrad level does not really translate into being capable of pursuing both at a graduate level. You will be better positioned to judge this for yourself once you have taken some graduate level courses (which you should be able to do during your undergraduate studies). Right now this seems like a bit of a premature concern. PhD studies are not "undergraduate studies, but more advanced", they are a whole another beast entirely.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you go after an interdisciplinary PhD that will combine Computer Science and Physics? There are so many topics to be explored such as complexity/network theory in physics, and machine learning applications in physics. You can also work on smart algorithms that filter data from large experiments in particle physics, neutron physics, condensed matter physics, etc. You can work on computational physics problems in nuclear physics, atomic theory, fluid dynamics, etc.

It would be useful to know your specific interests in Physics and Computer Science. However, in my opinion, most physics research nowadays is conducted on computers.

Answer (score 4):

There are 24 hours in a day. The MS in computer science will require ~8 hours of that, and the PhD in physics will also require ~8 hours of that. Since there's no way to add more hours to a day, this will only work if:

- You work more hours a day than most people would be comfortable with. You could conceivably do this, but there's a high chance of burnout.
- You take longer than normal to complete both programs (e.g. by doing both of them part-time).

Comment: Writing that a PhD takes only 8 hours a day is well below what the typical student actually uses and makes this sound a lot more feasible that it really is.

Comment: @quarague: not necessarily. Most students only take that long since they have never learned how to structure work efficiently and make it goal oriented. If I had to do my Ph.D. again, I'd could do it in a 3rd of the time and still hold down a full time job on the side. That was one of my key eye openers when changing from academia to industry. So if the OP has relevant project managements experiences from the real world, this may indeed be possible.

Comment: I disagree with that assessment. Research is really damn hard, especially in more theoretical fields. There are a lot of fruitless hours spent reading paper after paper and textbook after textbook during a PhD. That wastage decreases over time as students learn how to do research better, but early on it is a real fight.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, I know of someone who did a PhD in physics and also completed a master's in electrical engineering along the way. I didn't know her personally because she finished a few years before I joined, but it didn't sound like my advisor thought that was a very good gesture.

I don't know how she did it, but she didn't stay in academia. She opted to pursue a more financially lucrative route with the EE master's, I believe. However, she was pretty accomplished based on the papers she had authored.

I personally wouldn't recommend it because you have to be a uniquely capable individual and because you will probably somewhat lightly torch some political bridges by double dipping in that way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible depending on the rules of the university. The university where I did my PhD allowed graduate students to add masters degree's within the same college. One person in my Physics PhD program took one CS class per semester for the duration of the PhD and completed the MS and PhD in the same semester.

Answer (score 1):

"Possible" here has at least two connotations.

1. Will any university let me do it?
2. Can it be done?

For the first, you'd have to ask individual universities. For the second ... well, not for most people.  John von Neumann got a BA in engineering and a PhD in mathematics at the same time at two different universities, but JVN was one of the great geniuses of the 20th century and was also famous for working faster than anyone on the planet. For the vast majority of people (usually very bright people) getting either of these degrees would be a more than full time task.

You might find places where you could do both part time.

Finally, you are a freshman returning to school. Good for you. But, first figure out college. Then see. You won't be applying to grad school for a while.

Answer (score 0):

It is very much possible.

A master's degree in CS is just choosing one specialization field from your undergrad and doing further study.

Since you are double majoring in CS and physics, you have the necessary backgrounds in both. So, I don't see why you cannot do that.

However, I want to point out that you should do some introspection regarding your decision. Think again if it is justified to take all that pain at this stage in your life.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of possibility, I I think such an effort would be futile.

Do you want to be a physicist?

If yes, then you don't need to do a CS Masters. You will learn what ever CS knowledge you need during the course of your PhD. A PhD necessarily involves a lot of self study, and some of that could be learning CS material.

If no, then the PhD in physics is pointless. A PhD trains you to be a researcher in that field. It's not just classes and book-knowledge but is where you do your own research. So if you don't want to be a physicist, your financial and mental health will be better off if you get straight into whatever you do want to do.

Most of the reasons for doing a Masters, like boosting your admission prospects or preparing to start a PhD, don't apply if you do them simultaneously.

I understand the FOMO of knowledge and the feeling of wanting to be an expert in everything. But at some point you need to qddeot that you can't specialize in everything, and trust your ability to self study  (or at least informally study) the new things you want or need to learn.